# SDWebImage completion Block

Tags: ios, swift3, sdwebimage

Im using SDWebImage code, to download an image from internet.
[GitHub SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
Im Doing this in Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

I want to resize it once it is downloaded, but I can't have image size until I Download the image. (To make it resize proportionally)

So, my question is, is there a way to have a completion block to execute some code when the image has finish being downloaded? I can`t seem to find on github project info about the completion of the download.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I Found it! Post it in case someone else needs it.

I used this to load from web

```
imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: news.imageURL))
```

But for load and have a completing block I need to do:

```
 imgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: news.imageURL)) { (image, error, cache, url) in
            // Your code inside completion block
        }
```

Comment: the completing block helps me

Answer (score 9):

Here's some code right out of one of the SDWebImage example files, you can find more examples here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/Examples

**Swift Version:**

```
imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString), completed: {
                (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                // your code
            })
```

**Objective-C Version:**

```
- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.imageURL) {
        __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
        __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = self.imageView;
        [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:self.imageURL
                          placeholderImage:nil
                                   options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                                  progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize, NSURL *targetURL) {
                                      if (!activityIndicator) {
                                          [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
                                          activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
                                          [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                                      }
                                  }
                                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                     [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                                     activityIndicator = nil;
                                 }];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.